# Straight line in complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

I searched and found that the line 
$$y=mx+b$$
is expressed in complex plane as 
$$0=\mathrm{Re}((m+i)z+b)$$

My question is : why not expressing it simply as $$ z=x + i (mx+b) $$

Comment: In complex analysis we primarily deal with complex valued functions of a complex variable. The former expression exhibit the line $y=mx+b$ as the zero set of the real part of the 1st degree polynomial $(m+i)z+b$, while the later just parametrizes it as we would do in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Why bringing complex analysis into the playground if we are not gonna use it?

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $z = x+i(mx+b)$, then $$
(m+i)z + b = (m+i)(x+i(mx + b)) + b\\
= mx+mi(mx + b) + ix -(mx + b) + b\\
= mx -mx-b+b + i(m^2x + mb + x)\\
= i(m^2x + mb + x)
$$
which is pure imaginary (with real part $0$). On the other hand, if $z$ is such that $(m+i)z + b$ is pure imaginary, then if we set $z = x+iy$ with $x, y$ real we get
$$
(m+i)z + b = (m+i)(x+yi) + b\\
= mx + xi + myi - y + b\\
= mx-y+b + i(x+my)
$$
which implies that $mx - y + b = 0$ or $y = mx + b$. This gives $z = x + i(mx + b)$.

This means that the two criteria are equivalent. Why would you choose one over the other? That depends entirely on what you want to do with it afterwards. I can't read the minds of whichever author gave you the $0=\operatorname{Re}((m+i)z+b)$ criterion, but presumably, it was the best choice for whatever they wanted to use it for.